# jQuery span class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a span with a text inside it like :

```
<span class="characters-count">&#40;160 Characters Left&#41;</span>
```

given the span a class in this case `.characters-count` , when i tried class selector using jQuery to get the text inside span :

```
$(".characters-count")[0].text();
```

it returns undefined !

However this selector works well :

```
$("span.characters-count").text();
```

anyone can explain what is happening ?

Comment: You seem to think the selector is what is different, but **why do you have the `[0]` in the line that doesn't work?**

Comment: your code `$(".characters-count")[0].text();` is not suposed to work check console for error

Comment: @nnnnnn sorry i didnt get that part , what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: Look carefully at your own code - the line that doesn't work has `[0]` just before `.text()`. Why?

Comment: @nnnnnn because class selector will return a list

Comment: So why do you *not* have it in the line that does work? `$("any selector")` will return a list of zero or more elements. Or actually an array-like jQuery object containing zero or more elements. But jQuery methods belong to the jQuery object, not to the individual elements.

Comment: check this `console.log($(".characters-count")[0].text());` and this `console.log($(".characters-count"));` you will have your answer

Comment: @nnnnnn because i only had 1 item , so it worked , you are correct but in my case i was testing a single element.

Comment: No, it worked because `.text()` is a jQuery method. It doesn't matter whether you're testing a single element, `$("span.characters-count")` will always return a "list".

Comment: @nnnnnn so why didnt this work with pure class selector ?

Comment: @nnnnnn do you mean that removing [0] will work ?

Comment: @nnnnnn i think this is the explaination i was looking for , thank you , if you wish you can add detailed answer , and it will be selected as correct one.

Comment: dont use Array type. use jQuery eq() : Example: $("span.characters-count").eq(0).text();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("span.characters-count").text();
```

In our case you work with jQuery Object that has `text` method

```
$(".characters-count")[0].text();
```

In this case you work with [actual DOM element](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/) (like `document.getElementByClassName('characters-count')[0]`) that does not have `text` method

Answer (score 1):

you need to use innerText instead of text() when you use $(".characters-count")[0]    check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/4q0ohzhk/)

```
 $(".characters-count")[0].innerText
```

Comment: you should try your solution before submitting please.

Comment: @ProllyGeek i think you need to chcek my fiddle

Comment: sorry i had a type all that time innerHtml instead of innerHTML , thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log($(".characters-count:first").text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="characters-count">&#40;160 Characters Left&#41;</span>
```

try something like this:

```
$(".characters-count:first").text()
```

Check here, why it was not working for you.

```
//This will return dom element, so it doesn't have `text()` method, that's why it was throwing error for you.
    console.log($(".characters-count:first")[0]); 


// This will return object of an element, you can use jQuery selectors to get first element from collection and set text to it
     console.log($("span.characters-count"));
     console.log($("span.characters-count:first").text
```

);

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(".characters-count").text();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/trs8h7nL/)